# How to Bind a TServerSocket to a specific IP address

Tags: delphi, ip-address, serversocket

Does any one know any way to bind a Delphi TServerSocket component to accept requests only on a specific local address?

The server has several IPs but it is requires that server application to accept requests on one IP only when its running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TServerSocket` does not directly expose the feature you are asking for, however it is doable with a little workaround.

You need to derive a new class from `TServerSocket` in order to gain access to the protected `TAbstractSocket.Address` property. That is the value that `TServerSocket` binds to. Since the property is not normally accessible, it remains an empty string, which is the same as binding to `0.0.0.0` (aka `INADDR_ANY`, ie all local IPs).

Once you can access the `Address` property, you can set it to whatever IP you want prior to activating the server, and the server will bind accordingly.

For example:

```
type
  TServerSocketAccess = class(TServerSocket)
  end;

TServerSocketAccess(ServerSocket1).Address := '192.168.0.1';
ServerSocket1.Active := True;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Remy. This code is successfully updating the server socket address value. However server application keep responding to all other IP addresses even after the address property is explicitly set to an IP. Do you have any idea why? Is it Delphi socket limitation?

Comment: @LastManStanding what you describe can happen **only when** the `Address` is blank at the time that the server is activated. The listening socket gets bound to whatever IP has been set, and can only accept connections on that IP. Binding to a blank `Address` allows connections on any IP. You must set `Address` before setting `Active` to true.