# Bind TServerSocket to a specific IP address in C++ Builder (10.1.2)

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I am still using deprecated TServerSocket component.

I would like to bind TServerSocket to a specific IP. This question has been previously asked before for Delphi in this site: [How to Bind a TServerSocket to a specific IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094158/how-to-bind-a-tserversocket-to-a-specific-ip-address)

However I couldn't make it work in C++ Builder.

My code is:

```
class ServerWrapper : private TServerSocket {
 public:
      ServerWrapper();

 private:

};


ServerWrapper::ServerWrapper()
   : TServerSocket (0)
{
    //---
}

ServerWrapper* pServer =0;

//...
//..
//.

// And in a function: 

pServer = new ServerWrapper;
pServer->Address = "192.168.0.1" ;
pServer->Active = true;
```

However it doesn't compile.
It says:
E2247 'TAbstractSocket::Address' is not accessible

I am using C++ Builder 10.1.2 Berlin by the way.

Comment: Thank you for at least acknowledging that it's deprecated :-)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you did not translate the Delphi code to C++ correctly.

For one thing, you are using **private** inheritance instead of **public** inheritance. So all public and protected members inherited from `TServerSocket` will be private in `ServerWrapper`.  Delphi has no notion of protected/private inheritance, only public inheritance.

But more importantly, Delphi has a notion of **implicit friendship**. Within a unit, all classes have full access to private/protected members of other classes that are declared in the same unit.  That includes *inherited* protected members.  The Delphi example in the other question takes advantage of that feature, by declaring a local helper class to implicitly gain public access to the `Address` property for the unit that declares the helper.

But C++ has no notion of implicit friendship.  To translate the Delphi example to C++, you have to **explicitly promote** access to the protected `Address` property.

A *literal* translation of the Delphi code would look like this in C++:

```cpp
class TServerSocketAccess : public TServerSocket
{
public:
    __property Address;
   // or:
   // using TServerSocket::Address;
};

((TServerSocketAccess*)ServerSocket1)->Address = "192.168.0.1";
ServerSocket1->Active = true;
```

Applied to your `ServerWrapper` class, it would look like this:

```cpp
class ServerWrapper : public TServerSocket
{
public:
    ServerWrapper();

    __property Address;
   // or:
   // using TServerSocket::Address;
};

ServerWrapper::ServerWrapper()
    : TServerSocket (0)
{
    //---
}

ServerWrapper* pServer = 0;
//...
pServer = new ServerWrapper;
pServer->Address = "192.168.0.1";
pServer->Active = true;
```

Comment: Without adding "__property Address;" line to the public part of ServerWrapper class, All public, protected and private inheritance yielded the same error result. But of course when I add "__property Address;" in public inheritance it works now :)

Comment: @Aethon yes, because `Address` is declared as `protected` in `TServerSocket`, so you need a `public` statement to promote it to public